# Why doesn't the order in which member functions of a C++ structure are defined matter?

Tags: c++, struct, member-functions

I am learning about structures in C++ and I noticed something peculiar:

The order in which the member functions of a structure are defined doesn't matter when it comes to calling the functions.

For e.g.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct var
{
    int returnTwo()
    {
        return 2*returnOne();
    }
    int returnOne()
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    var a;
    cout<<a.returnTwo();
    return 0;
}
```

The above code compiles and outputs 2!

Had the functions been defined normally (not inside any structures) then the above code would have not got complied.

Why is this difference there? Are there any specific reasons?

Thank you.

Comment: The order of definition of functions doesn't matter, as long as the compiler has visibility of a *declaration* of each function at or before the statement that calls it. The compiler has visibility of the complete `struct`/`class` definition, so has visibility of all the functions declared within it.    So member functions of a `struct`/`class` can access all members of that `struct`/`class` even if the members are declared later in the `struct`/`class` definition.  And regardless of whether the functions are defined inline or after the `struct`/`class` definition.

Comment: " functions been defined normally". Inline definition is also normal! There are some pros and cons to do that e.g. solving circular deps vs. better optimization and some more. The order doesn't matter as the access is via names ( symbols ) and not the nth function number. Even if it goes over numbers, purely hypothetical, declaration must also be visible. As your observation is partly wrong, there are no specific reasons as everything compiles and works as expected if you include your class definition which contains member function declarations to your translation unit.(main.cpp)

Comment: You're right about the general rule: a function must have been declared prior to the point where it's called. But there's a special rule for class definitions. This is oversimplified, but the compiler waits until the end of the class definition to resolve names that are used inside the class. So it's okay for a member function whose definition is inside the class definition to call another member function that isn't declared until after the point where it's used.